# Sorting XYChart Series Data

Tags: java, sorting, graph, javafx

Hello I have added data to a XYSeries and am trying to get that data sorted from shortest length to largest. I don't know how to manipulate this data, Can anyone help me out. This is my code:

```
           xLabel = "Link Id";
           yLabel = "Length (Km)";

           bc = new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
           bc.setTitle(gTitle);

           //Set x/y Axis Label
           //xAxis.setLabel(xLabel);
           yAxis.setLabel(yLabel);

           //double[] lengthArray = new double[linkIds.length];
           XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
           series1.setName(xLabel);

           for (Integer m = 0; m < linkIdsOTS.length; m++) {
                double length = netPlan.getLinkLengthInKm(otsLayerId, m);
                //lengthArray[i] = length;    
                series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(m.toString(), length));
           }

           bc.getData().addAll(series1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Series` and `Data` are properly typed, you should be able to do

```
series1.getData().sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(d -> d.getYValue().doubleValue()));
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartSortTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        String cats = "ABCDEFGH" ;
        Series<String, Number> series = new Series<>();
        series.setName("Random data");
        chart.getData().add(series);
        Stream.of(cats.split(""))
            .map(cat -> new Data<String, Number>(cat, rng.nextDouble()))
            .forEach(series.getData()::add);

        series.getData().sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(d -> d.getYValue().doubleValue()));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(chart, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```